# Negative rgba in sass calculating

Tags: sass

Can I achieve something like this in sass?

```
ul.menu li{
    background-color: rgba(0, 196, 196, 1) + rgba(1, -16, -16, 0);
}
```

The outcome should be 1,180,180,1.
Is this possible with sass?

Comment: Did you *try* it?  It's unclear why you are asking this question when you could just as easily test it for yourself.

Comment: Yeah duh.. why else would I ask it.

Comment: Why the "duh?"  People come to SO all the time and ask questions that would clearly be answered if they ran the code themselves.  If you ran the code, then it would have given you a specific error that even a 5 year old could understand.

Answer (score -1):

you must merge the values.. it is not possible otherwise.

Example for your question :

```
ul.menu li{
    background-color: rgba(1, 180, 180, 1);
    // or: background-color: rgba(0+1, 196-16, 196-16, 1+0);
}
```

Good luck